# Flask Config Sytax Error - Independent of File Contents

Tags: python, flask

I'm creating a Flask application, and attempting to load configuration from a file. Not too hard right? I'm loading it like this:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile('../config.py')
```

The config file looks something like this:

```
# App settings
DEBUG = True
TESTING = True
```

The issue is, it returns an error...
[root@helios gdn]# env/bin/python run.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 3, in <module>
    from gdn import app
  File "/var/www/gdn/gdn/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    app.config.from_pyfile('../config.py')
  File "/var/www/gdn/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flask/config.py", line 129, in from_pyfile
    exec(compile(config_file.read(), filename, 'exec'), d.__dict__)
  File "/var/www/gdn/gdn/../config.py", line 1
    DEBUG = True
                ^
```

That is strange... So I tried replacing the contents, even with the lines `print 'foo' / print 'bar'` and it returns the same error, referencing the end of the line. Empty files work, and single lines work, but multiple lines? Nope. Each line is ended with a single `\n`, just like the rest of my Python files. I cannot find what is causing the issue.

I'm running Python 2.6.6 on a CentOS VM.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your **config.py** file is present just inside the project root and you can call that config file like this

```
app.config.from_object('config')
```

Hope it helps !